# How to implement custom theme functions (theme_textfield, theme_form_element) for some forms only?

Tags: theming, forms

How to implement custom theme functions like [theme_textfield](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_textfield/7.x) or [theme_form_element](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_form_element/7.x)?

I know we can do it using [hook_theme_registry_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7.x):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter().
 */
function krown_admin_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {

  //Override some Drupal defaul theme functions

  $theme_registry['textfield']['theme path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'krown_admin');
  $theme_registry['textfield']['function'] = 'krown_admin_theme_textfield';
  $theme_registry['textarea']['theme path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'krown_admin');
  $theme_registry['textarea']['function'] = 'krown_admin_theme_textarea';
  $theme_registry['form_element']['theme path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'krown_admin');
  $theme_registry['form_element']['function'] = 'krown_admin_theme_form_element';
  $theme_registry['form_element_label']['theme path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'krown_admin');
  $theme_registry['form_element_label']['function'] = 'krown_admin_theme_form_element_label';

}
```

The problem with this approach, is that the custom functions are applied on all website. I just want to apply them for some forms or for a specific theme.

Answer (score 1):

Those theme functions don't get a reference to the form where the element is used. Therefore, they cannot be used to alter an element for a single form.

Every form element accepts [#theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#theme), so you can alter the #theme function used for those form fields in a single form. This is what Drupal does in [`node_filter_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.admin.inc/function/node_filter_form/7.x).

```
  $form['filters'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Show only items where'),
    '#theme' => 'exposed_filters__node',
  );
```

[`theme_exposed_filters()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/theme_exposed_filters/7.x) then does its job.

```
  $form = $variables['form'];
  $output = '';

  if (isset($form['current'])) {
    $items = array();
    foreach (element_children($form['current']) as $key) {
      $items[] = drupal_render($form['current'][$key]);
    }
    $output .= theme('item_list', array('items' => $items, 'attributes' => array('class' => array('clearfix', 'current-filters'))));
  }

  $output .= drupal_render_children($form);

  return '<div class="exposed-filters">' . $output . '</div>';
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work with `theme_form_element()` or `theme_form_element_label()`.